# Reindexing a huge table is taking less than a minute

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

People often ask how to reduce the time in rebuilding the indexes on a huge SQL Server table.

But I have the reverse issue. Its a table of 5 million+ rows and when we Rebuild one of the primary non-clustered index which was fragmented up to 97%,  it really went quick and was done in less than a minute.

Does SSMS say 'Rebuilding Index Completed' prematurely, but the actual re-indexing continues to happen in the background for hours on? We use SQL Server 2012.

This is the first place where I have witnessed rebuilding non-clustered indexes on any table of any huge size, finish literally in less than a minute, which frankly boggles my mind. Especially since people always seem to ask the exact opposite question.

Any explanation on this would  be highly appreciated!

Comment: "huge" is a vague term. 5M rows is not that much for modern hardware. In our system a full rebuild of all indexes on a table with 7M rows (~2GB) took 1 min 18 seconds. A table with 130M rows (~33GB) took 34 minutes. It should mostly depend on the overall size of the index (in bytes), not the number of rows as such.

Comment: Got it. Never knew it is the size of the Index. I always for some reason kept thinking 5 million rows, it takes lot of time to index. Thanks for clarifying.